# Case-insensitive sorted Set - keep same string with different case

Tags: java, sorting, set, case-insensitive

Today I have a case-insensitive sorted `Set` like:

```java
Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
set.add("foo");
set.add("FOO");
set.add("bar");
System.out.println(set.toString());
```

The output of this is:

```
[bar, foo]
```

But what I really wanted was:

```
[bar, FOO, foo]
```

That is, I want the *sorting* of the set to be case-insensitive, but I want to be able to have same string with different cases (like "foo" and "FOO") in the set, without the last one being discarded.

I know I could sort a `List`, but in my case I need a `Set`.

Is there a neat way of doing this in Java?

Comment: I don't think you're guaranteed to get `FOO` before `foo` with `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`, if that's what you're expecting. It's an insensitive sort, so to the sort, `FOO` and `foo` are the same thing and may therefore appear in any order.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The order of `FOO` and `foo` is not that important, the tricky part is to get both of them in the set, and at the same time `bar` before `FOO`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably want to use a comparator that orders case insensitively then uses case sensitive ordering as a tiebreaker.

So something like:

```
Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>((a, b) -> {
    int insensitive = String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(a, b);
    return insensitive==0 ? a.compareTo(b) : insensitive;
});
```

Comment: *Man* I love lambdas.